# Lucene 4.8.1 search not finding match

Tags: lucene

Editing my original question to better state what I'm battling with. Here is my problem domain. I'm in the testing department of a software company. We write groovy scripts to test the software. The software uses a properties file containing a key value pair for warning and error messages it logs.

What I want to do is index all my groovy scripts (300+ of then) and then iterate through my properties file and check which of my scripts is checking for that particular error message.

example of the properties file:

```
B_C_Patched=Patched
```

This is just one string pair, there is over 3000 of them.

Below is the indexer class I written so for:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.core.WhitespaceAnalyzer
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term
import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher
import org.apache.lucene.search.ScoreDoc
import org.apache.lucene.search.TermQuery
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory
import org.apache.lucene.util.Version
import org.apache.lucene.search.RegexpQuery

public class Indexer {
    private final Config config
    private final String SCRIPT_PATH = "path"
    private final String CONTENTS = "contents"
    //Store the index in memory
    private final RAMDirectory idx = new RAMDirectory()
    def Analyzer analyzer = new WhitespaceAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_48)

    public Indexer(Config config) {
        this.config = config;
    }
    //Save index to Memory
    public indexScripts() {
        IndexWriterConfig idxConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_48, analyzer)
        IndexWriter iwriter = new IndexWriter(idx, idxConfig)

        //Traverse the folder and index both the file path and its contents
        config.getScriptFolder().traverse { file ->
            if (file.isFile()) {
                Document doc = new Document()
                String path = file.name
                Field pathField = new StringField(SCRIPT_PATH, path, Field.Store.YES)
                doc.add(pathField)

                String content = file.text
                doc.add(new StringField(CONTENTS, content, Field.Store.YES))
                println("Added file: " + file.name)
                iwriter.addDocument(doc)
            }
        }
        iwriter.close()
    }

    public ArrayList<String> searchIndex(String checkFor, boolean regEx = false) {
        //Open a reader to the index in memory
        def IndexReader indexReader = IndexReader.open(idx)
        def IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(indexReader)
        def ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>()

        //Parse the query according to the string provided
        if (!regEx) {
            TermQuery query = new TermQuery(new Term(CONTENTS, checkFor))
            println query
            ScoreDoc[] hits = indexSearcher.search(query, 400).scoreDocs
            if (hits.length > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
                    def Document hitDoc = indexSearcher.doc(hits[i].doc)
                    results.add(hitDoc.get(SCRIPT_PATH))
                    return results
                }
            }
            results = []
            return results
        } else {
            RegexpQuery query = new RegexpQuery(new Term(checkFor))
            ScoreDoc[] hits = indexSearcher.search(query, null, 400).scoreDocs
            if (hits.size() != null) {
                for (int i = 0; i < hits.length; i++) {
                    def Document hitDoc = indexSearcher.doc(hits[i].doc)
                    results.add(hitDoc.get(SCRIPT_PATH))
                    return results
                }
            }
            results = []
            return results
        }
        indexReader.close()
    }
}
```

The above code gives me 0 results. I want it to do a exact match of the B_C_Patched part of the string so I do split the string at the "=" and save the 1st part as the checkFor variable.

I have tired different analyzers query parser and all return 0.

Please help ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess: you are using `StandardAnalyzer` (which uses `StandardTokenizer`). The latter splits words by using [Unicode word boundaries](http://unicode.org/reports/tr29). And the underscore in your string (`B_C_Patched`) has a couple of these.

So when you index this, it gets split into `B`, `C` and `Patched`. But when you construct your query using `TermQuery`, it does not analyse it and treats as one term. To fix this, use `QueryParser` and feed it with `contents:B_C_Patched` - returned query should be yielding a different result.

Comment: Thanks for the input I will give it a try and report back.

Comment: Again thx for feedback, But what I really need is for the indexing not to split the string, as it a key value pair as in "B_C_Patched=File where patched". So I tried a keyword Analyzer in the indixing part with a Field.index.NOT_ANALYZED and I still get no results back. Am I using wrong Analyzer in the index part?

Comment: Sry forgot to mention in above comment I want to a exact match

Comment: You can use any analyzer you want, just make sure you pass the same analyzer instance to the `QueryParser`. Have you done that?

Comment: Just tried it mindas, I created a Analyzer outside of the two methodes and use it in both. Then I constucted my query as follows:
QueryParser queryParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_48, CONTENTS, analyzer)
            Query query = queryParser.parse(checkFor)

and still getting 0 results back

Comment: It's probably best if you could edit your question and create self-contained, runnable example using `RAMDirectory`. Plus, your code doesn't seem to be Java in which Lucene is written.

Comment: The code is Groovy :), I'll edit my question and copy in my entire class.